# voxel representation of neural image data using vispy

Tags: imaging, voxel, vispy

I have fluorescence imaging data of the neurons of the brain, which is basically a 3D image defined by its voxels. I would like to display it using vispy to show the depth and be able to rotate and view the data from all directions.

I don't want a projection but would like to represent each pixel as a point and display them using vispy.
 I looked at how to display points using vispy.
http://vispy.org/examples/basics/gloo/display_points.html

My idea was to use the size(x*y) of the image as positions of the vertex and the pixel data as the color of the vertex. But I am unable to achieve what I want.
I am new to openGl/vispy. Any suggestion or ideas would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Volume rendering in Vispy is in the making: https://github.com/vispy/vispy/pull/612 This PR should be merged within two weeks.